# Android Zip file access

Tags: android, zip

is there any way how to open zip file and access it as it was unzipped in Android? I have zip file with data, which I need to be accessed by application and I don't want to unzip it to some folder and open it from there. So I want data access directly from zip file without unzipping it. I am now trying to use ZipFile, but I haven't found any usage, which might be usefull for me. Is this approach even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I've been using to 'unzip on the fly' and create drawables.

```
    private void createBitmapDrawables() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("images.zip");  
             ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
             try {
                 ZipEntry ze;
                 while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                     int count;
                     while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                         baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                     }
                     String file = ze.getName();
                     byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
                     drawable = createBitmapDrawable(bytes, file);

                 }
             } finally {
                 zis.close();
             }


}
```

Pretty much from the Android Dev site.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well as every file, in order to use its content you have to open and read it in memory and typically at this purpose you use an InputStream. In this case you have to read an entry of a zip file so you can iterate trough the zip entry and when you find the entry you are looking for you can obtain a ZipInputStream for it and read like a normal file

Comment: Thanks, I have come up to ZipInputStream, but I succeded only, when I saved ZipInputStream to a file. I must not save it as a file but process it on the go? How to make "virtual" file, which will be readed and not saved in the memory?

Comment: well that depends on the data consumer. For instance your application could read data directly from the InputStream or from a byte array.. that is up to you